# In PHP given a month string such as "November" how can I return 11 without using a 12 part switch statement?

Tags: php, date, mktime

I.e.

```
Month        Returns
January      1
February     2
March        3
April        4
May          5
June         6
July         7
August       8
September    9
October      10
November     11
December     12
```

I've seen examples using mktime when given the number of the month and returning the month string, but not the reverse.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
echo date('n', strtotime('November')); // returns 11
```

---

If you have to do this often, you might consider using an array that has these values hardcoded:

```
$months = array( 1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April',
                 5 => 'May',     6 => 'June',     7 => 'July',  8 => 'August',
                 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November',
                 12 => 'December');
```

Can also do it the other way round though, using the names for the keys and numbers for values.

With the names for values you do

```
echo array_search('November', $months); // returns 11
```

and with names for keys you do

```
echo $months['November']; // returns 11
```

I find using the numbers for the keys somewhat better *in general*, though for your UseCase the names for keys approach is likely more comfortable. With just 12 values in the array, there shouldn't be much of a difference between the array approches.

A quick benchmark noted a difference of 0.000003s vs 0.000002s, whereas the time conversion takes 0.000060s on my computer (read: might differ on other computer).

Comment: For those who prefer playing with objects, PHP 5.3 brings us `DateTime::createFromFormat('F', $month)->format('n')`

Comment: why not use the names as keys of the array, having the numbers as values ? Then, it would only be a matter of using `echo $months['November']` *(and would probably be faster than using `array_search` -- ok, I admit, doesn't matter much ^^ )*

Comment: @Pascal agreed. Was more like a personal preference than anything else. Updated.

Answer (score 7):

What about using [**`strtotime()`**](http://www.php.net/strtotime) to convert `November` to a timestamp, and, then, the [**`date()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function with the `n` format to get the corresponding number :

```
$ts = strtotime('november');
echo date('n', $ts);
```

Gives the following output :

```
11
```

And, just for fun, a portion of code such as the following one :

```
$months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', );
foreach ($months as $m) {
    $ts = strtotime($m);
    echo $m . ' : ' . date('n', $ts) . '<br />';
}
```

will give you the list of all month with their corresponding numbers -- showing that this idea will work for all 12 months, and not only November ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I can't imagine this is more efficient, but it works

```
$t = strtotime("March");
echo date('n',$t);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to set each string as a variable and make it = the respective number. But then again I'm pretty new, so I'm eager to see as well if there are any easier ways (=

Answer (score 1):

```
$months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 
                'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', );
foreach ($months as $m) {
    echo $m."=".date('n', strtotime($m))."<br>";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario probably the most efficient solution to this would be to create an associative array like:

```
$months = array("january" => 1, "february" => 2, "march" => 3, "april" => 4, "may" => 5, "june" => 6, "july" => 7, "august" => 8, "september" => 9, "october" => 10, "november" => 11, "december" => 12);
```

And then your lookups are super easy:

```
$month = "Nobember";
$monthNumber = $months[strtolower($month)];
```

Comment: You should probably check if the month doesnt exist, like Nobember.