# PHP convert month

Tags: php, date, format

is there anyway to convert date month numeric to string.

**e.g. for 1 convert to January, 2 => February, etc**

i tried below

```
<?php echo date('F', strtotime($member['dob_month'])); ?>
```

didnt work out

Comment: One can make an array...

Comment: What is `$member['dob_month']`? Is it an int 1..12? String?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP given a month string such as "November" how can I return 11 without using a 12 part switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701695/in-php-given-a-month-string-such-as-november-how-can-i-return-11-without-using)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$member['dob_month'],1,0); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$months = array(1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', ...);
echo $months[$member['dob_month']];
```

Given the value of `$member['dob_month']` is an 1-based integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('n', $member['dob_month']);
echo $date->format('F');
```

Note: In [`createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), use 'm' if the month has leading zeros, 'n' if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `date()` needs a timestamp for it´s second parameter and `strtotime($member['dob_month'])` does not result in a meaningfull timestamp if `$member['dob_month']` is a number from 1 to 12.

You can use something like:

```
date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $member['dob_month'], 1, 2010));
```