# How can I convert month name to number?

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP given a month string such as “November” how can I return 11 without using a 12 part switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701695/in-php-given-a-month-string-such-as-november-how-can-i-return-11-without-using)

How can I convert month name to month number in php without using an array? Is there any inbuilt function available in php?

Eg: If I use "January" from the variable, it should change to "01".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$monthName = 'January';
$date = date_parse($monthName);
$monthNumber = $date['month'];
```

Note that this will return `1`, not `01`, so change your display format accordingly.

Comment: Add this for formating: `$monthNumber = ($monthNumber < 10 ? '0' : '') . $monthNumber;`

Comment: Or `$monthNumber = substr("0$monthNumber", -2);` or `sprintf()` or ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this as there are no Enum in PHP as far as I know.

```
class Months
{
    const January  = 1;
    const Feburary = 2;
    // etc.
}

var $currentMonth = Months::January;
```

/J